# Map topics back to original dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have read data from excel into R, data comprises of 459 rows and 3 columns.

```
library(openxlsx)
datamg <- read.xlsx("GC1.xlsx",sheet=1,startRow = 1,colNames = 
TRUE,skipEmptyRows = TRUE)
head(datamg,3)

                  Q                                   Themes1     Themes2
1 yes I believe it . Because the risk limits       Nature of risk    <NA>
2 Yes but a very low risk                                   Other    <NA>
3 worried about potential regulations         Regulatory concerns    <NA>
```

I have created corpus using tm package. Also created a unigram using Rweka package.

```
tdm1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus1, control = list(tokenize = UnigramTokenizer))
inspect(tdm1)

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 877, documents: 459)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2714/399829
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
           Docs
Terms       149 15 204 206 256 258 279 358 400 74
  busi        0  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1  0
  chang       0  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  0
  compani     0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
  disrupt     1  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  0
  growth      0  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
  market      0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
  new         0  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0  0
  product     1  0   0   0   0   2   0   1   0  0
  risk        0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1  0
  technolog   1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  0
```

Thereafter used topicmodels package to obtain top 8 topics. Each topic comprises of 2 terms

```
#Topic Modelling
dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(tdm1)
library(topicmodels)
lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 10) # find 8 topics
term <- terms(lda, 2) # first 7 terms of every topic
(term <- apply(term, MARGIN = 2, paste, collapse = ", "))



      Topic 1 Topic 2   Topic 3   Topic 4     Topic 5  Topic 6     Topic 7  Topic 8 Topic 9    Topic 10 
[1,] "busi"  "disrupt" "busi"    "risk"      "new"    "new"       "mani"   "chang" "chang"    "risk"   
[2,] "new"   "compani" "product" "technolog" "market" "technolog" "market" "price" "competit" "disrupt"
```

I require help to link these topics back to each row of the original dataset.

Example:

```
         Q                                   Themes1     Themes2       Topic Mapped
    1 yes I believe it . Because the risk limits       Nature of risk    <NA>  
    2 Yes but a very low risk                                   Other    <NA>
    3 worried about potential regulations         Regulatory concerns    <NA>
```

I thought I could do this with grep, but unable to make it work. 
Appreciate your help on this. Thank you

Comment: What's supposed to be in `datamg$TopicMapped`?

Comment: You have 3 rows in your data frame and 2 rows in your output. Are you not showing the 3rd row of output?

Comment: @KenS. thank you for your response. datamg$TopicMapped is meant to have the Topic 1, Topic 2, etc allocated to respective row.                                                    Please ignore Theme1 and Theme2, as I tried to manually allocate topics from my understanding of what was in column 1 (Q).

Comment: @CPak thank you for response. Please ignore Theme1 and Theme2 as per my previous comment above.  The datamd$TopicMapped is supposed to the best fit from the topics identified from topicmodeling.

Answer (score 2):

In order to map them back to the original dataset, you have to add unique identifiers to each document in the Corpus & Document Term Matrix. Since you do not have row ids (or some kind of unique key), I create a row id based on the row number and add it to the original dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)
library(tidytext)

datamg$doc_id <- 1:nrow(datamg)

datamg <- datamg %>% 
  select(doc_id, Q) %>%
  rename('text' = Q)
```

I keep only those two columns and give them those names 'doc_id' and 'text' because it is required by the tm package (DataframeSource function) when attaching the ids to the Corpus.

```
myCorpus1 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(datamg))
```

With this corpus you can create the DTM and run your LDA model as you did. After that, you create the 'gamma matrix' (per-document-per-topic):

```
document_topic <- as.data.frame(tidy(lda, matrix = "gamma"))
document_topic$document <- as.integer(document_topic$document)

document_topic <- document_topic %>%
  group_by(document) %>%
  top_n(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which gives you a data frame consisting of each row id with a topic (you might get more than one topic, for example with sparse sentences that can fall in many topics). Then you can join it back with your original data frame

```
df_join <- inner_join(datamg, document_topic, by = c("Q" = "document"))
```